# How can I control multiple widgets in a loop in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

When creating controls in MFC (either dynamically created or using the MFC Resource Editor), each control has a unique resource ID. So, I predefined control resource IDs in the header file, and used `GetDlgItem(int)` function in the for loop when I needed multiple control manipulations.

Here is MFC example:

```
// ResourceID.h
#define IDC_BTN1 WM_USER + 101
#define IDC_BTN2 WM_USER + 102
#define IDC_BTN3 WM_USER + 103
...
#define IDC_BTN10 WM_USER + 110

// When getting the checked state of buttons 1 to 10
for(int i = IDC_BTN1; i <= IDC_BTN10; i++)
  ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(i))->GetCheck();
```

Now I want to do the same in Qt (processing multiple widgets in batch). I have placed 10 buttons using **Qt Designer** (not the dynamically created). However, Qt can only be accessed by object like `ui->pushButton`, so I cannot control multiple widgets with loop.

So, my question is

1. Qt widgets have IDs that can be assigned sequentially, such as MFC's resource IDs?
2. How can I control multiple widgets?
3. I can control multiple widgets using the QPushButton* array as follows:

```
// in header 
QPushButton *btnArr[10];

// in constructor
btnArr[0] = ui->btn1;
btnArr[1] = ui->btn2;
...

// control multiple widgets
for(QPushButton *btn : btnArr)
  btn->hide();
```

It works, but is this the right way?

Comment: In your specific case, you could also place the multiple widgets in a parent widget to hide them at once. Your issue seems to be related to using a widget designer (which I never do). Hence, you don't have total control about the source code (i.e. how the buttons are stored) which you would have if you would write your code manually. I believe you have only two chances: either drop the widget designer or create an additional array for the button pointers which is initialized once (e.g. in the constructor).

Comment: Another option might be to name the buttons in a certain way so that you can find them by name later. Though, I would prefer a solution like in your last code snippet.

Comment: @Scheff Then, it's not the wrong way to create and use an additional array of button pointers. Thanks to comment. Designers are definitely one of Qt's great strengths for a Qt newbie like me, but sometimes it feels like the designer makes it harder to create what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are in the same parent. You can use [setObjectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) method to set the name for the buttons.

Then from the parent, you can access the buttons via object name by using [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) method. If the button names are in a rule like "button1", "button2"...then you can easily access the buttons in a loop.